# How to fetch filtered document based on List of objetcs in Mongodb using C# mongodb driver

Tags: c#, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

Consider this scenario: I wanted to fetch the filtered document from the documents collection of Student.

```
[  
   {  
      name:'arun',
      gender:'Male',
      physics:88,
      maths:87,
      english:78
   },
   {  
      name:'rajesh',
      gender:'Male',
      physics:96,
      maths:100,
      english:95
   },
   {  
      name:'moorthy',
      gender:'Male',
      physics:89,
      maths:90,
      english:70
   }]
```

I wanted to filter based on array having value as

```
[  
       {  
          name:'arun',
          gender:'Male',
          physics:88,
          maths:87,
          english:78
       },
       {  
          name:'rajesh',
          gender:'Male',
          physics:96,
          maths:100,
          english:95
       }]
```

And I wanted to match name, gender and physics to get the filtered documents. I don't want to use foreach. How can I get a filtered list of documents?

Comment: Tried using filterdefination filterDef.In<object>(x => new { x.name, x.gender, x.physics }, students). Its not working giving exception  as Exception occured while processing students Data due to : Expression not supported: new <>f__AnonymousType0`4(

Answer (score 1):

This query will be slightly tricky as it requires matching any item and at the same time, all the properties in the item must be matched.

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $or: [
      {
        $and: [
          {
            $eq: [
              "$name",
              "arun"
            ]
          },
          {
            $eq: [
              "$gender",
              "Male"
            ]
          },
          {
            $eq: [
              "$physics",
              88
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        $and: [
          {
            $eq: [
              "$name",
              "rajesh"
            ]
          },
          {
            $eq: [
              "$gender",
              "Male"
            ]
          },
          {
            $eq: [
              "$physics",
              96
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7i_eqN9X9Kw)

In the MongoDB .NET way, you need to prepare the filter definition matching all the properties in the `student` first and add it into `filterDefinitions`. Next, with `Or` build the query that matches any item in `filterDefinitions`.

```cs
List<FilterDefinition<Student>> filterDefinitions = new List<FilterDefinition<Student>>();
foreach (Student student in searchStudents)
{
    FilterDefinition<Student> studentFilter = FilterDefinition<Student>.Empty;
    studentFilter &= Builders<Student>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Name, student.Name)
        & Builders<Student>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Gender, student.Gender)
        & Builders<Student>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Physics, student.Physics);

    filterDefinitions.Add(studentFilter);
}

List<Student> result = (await _collection.FindAsync(Builders<Student>.Filter.Or(filterDefinitions)))
    .ToList();
```