# How to find items in a collection that exist in a list based on 2 fields in MongoDB and C#

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a list of objects

```
var myList = new List<MyObject>{
   new MyObject{ name="user1", Code=1},
   new MyObject{ name="user2", Code=1},
   new MyObject{ name="user1", Code=2},
};
```

and this is what I have in my collection

```
[
   { name:"user1", Code:1},
   { name:"user2", Code:2},
   { name:"user3", Code:1},
   { name:"user4", Code:3},
   { name:"user1", Code:2}
]
```

I want to find items in my collection that matches items in the list based on `name` and `code`. The result should be

```
[
   { name:"user1", Code:1},
   { name:"user1", Code:2}
}
```

Is that possible with only `find` or I have to use `aggregate`?

Answer (score 0):

This question is similar to the question that I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75834357).

In short, the implementation of your filter criteria should be:

1. Match the object with all properties' values are matched.
2. Match any of the objects.

```cs
List<FilterDefinition<MyObject>> filters = new List<FilterDefinition<MyObject>>();
foreach (var obj in myList)
{
    FilterDefinition<MyObject> filter = Builders<MyObject>.Filter.Empty;
    filter &= Builders<MyObject>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Code, obj.Code);
    filter &= Builders<MyObject>.Filter.Eq(x => x.name, obj.name);

    filters.Add(filter);
}

List<MyObject> results = (await _collection.FindAsync(Builders<MyObject>.Filter.Or(filters)))
    .ToList();
```